# graph of the Cantor set in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, fractals

The interval $[0,1]$ of the real line, which we call $C_0$, and divide it into three equal subintervals. In this way we obtain the following intervals $[0,1/3]$,$[1/3,2/3]$,$[2/3,1]$, and we get rid of the interval $[1/3,2/3]$.
Then, we obtain the set $C_1=[0,1/3]\cup[2/3,1]$.
Now repeat the above process on each of the intervals $C_1$, then $C_2=[0,1/9]\cup[2/9,3/9]\cup[6/9,7/9]\cup[8/9,1]$
Proceeding in the same way we obtain $C_3,C_4,C_5,C_6,\dots$
Thus we define the Cantor set as the intersection of all $C_i$ constructed before.
Now the goal is to obtain the graph of the Cantor set in the different steps

Comment: Check here http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CantorSet/

Answer (score 8):

You can also use new-in-version-10 [NumberLinePlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberLinePlot.html). The last example in [NumberLinePlot >> Applications](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberLinePlot.html) slightly modified:

```
NumberLinePlot[NestList[# /. {a_, b_} :>
   Sequence[{a,2 a/3 + b/3}, { a/3 + 2 b/3, b}] &,
   Interval[{0, 1}], 5], {x, 0, 1},AspectRatio->1/4, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"],Thick]]/. Point[x_]:>Sequence[]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It may be an available answer:

In=

```
n = 5;
f = #/3 &; g = #/3 + 2/3 &;
Fission[list_] := Flatten@Through[{f, g}@list]
intervals = NestList[Fission, {Interval[{0, 1}]}, n];
segments[n_] := 
 intervals[[n]] /. Interval[{a_, b_}] :> Line[{{a, 0.1 n}, {b, 0.1 n}}]
Graphics[{Black, Array[segments, n + 1]}]
```

Out=

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you are in 11.1,`CantorMesh` will make your life easer:

```
NumberLinePlot[Interval @@@ (MeshPrimitives[#, 1] &@*CantorMesh /@ Range[4] /. 
    Line -> Flatten), PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0], Black]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]