# Plot certain variations of the Cantor set

Tags: plotting, graphics

In the post [graph of the Cantor set in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63966/graph-of-the-cantor-set-in-mathematica), there are many nice plots of the Cantor set.

It is possible to use Mathematica to produce

- the plot of a $360°$ rotation of the Cantor set around the point $1/2$?
- the plot of the set obtained by putting Cantor sets continuously "side by side" in the $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ square? That is, just "replacing the dots" in the Cantor set with vertical lines of length one

Comment: The answers to both questions are Yes. Are you looking for a free coding service?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the question correctly, we could make a mesh with [`CantorMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CantorMesh.html), convert it to lines with [`MeshPrimitives`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshPrimitives.html), then use a replacement rule to convert the lines to either annuli or rectangles to be wrapped in [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html).

*Rotated 360 degrees around $(1/2,0)$:*

```
Graphics[MeshPrimitives[CantorMesh[6], 1] /.
{Line[{{x1_}, {x2_}}] :> Annulus[{0.5, 0}, Sort[Abs[{0.5, 0.5} - {x1, x2}]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Extended vertically to the unit square:*

```
Graphics[MeshPrimitives[CantorMesh[6], 1] /. 
Line[{{x1_}, {x2_}}] :> Rectangle[{x1, 0}, {x2, 1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to make 2D Cantor plots:

```
CantorMesh[4, 2]
```

[image]

Change the first number to plot at higher levels. Change the second number to 3 for a 3D plot:

```
CantorMesh[2, 3]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But in the second part of the question I actually didn't mean a multi-dimensional cantor dust, but just "replacing the dots" in the cantor set with vertical lines of lenght one.

Comment: I answered the question you asked, not the one you intended to ask.

Comment: Technically you didn't: that picture is not  "the plot of the set obtained by putting Cantor sets continuously "side by side" in the $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ square". Thanks anyway for the effort, though.